# how to populate jcombobox with arrays that match specific criteria

Tags: java, arrays, jcombobox

When i try my code below the list isn't be populated with the specific arrays please help i'm pretty new to coding GUI in netbeans

```
private void bookingListJCBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    for(int i = 0;i<dataSource.getBookingList().size();i++){
        Bookings tempBooking = dataSource.getBookingList().get(i);

        boolean tempFinish = tempBooking.getFinish();
        String tempMechanic = tempBooking.getMechanic();
        String tempClerk = tempBooking.getClerk();
        String tempService  = tempBooking.getService();

       if(tempFinish == true){
         bookingListJCB.addItem(tempBooking);
         mechanicJTF.setText(tempMechanic);
         seriveceClerkJTF.setText(tempMechanic);
         serviceJTF.setText(""+tempService );
         finishJTF.setText(""+tempFinish);
        }
    }


    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Here is the Bookings class how i don't know why the combo box isn't displaying anything

```
public class Bookings {
private String vehicle;
private String clerk;
private String service;
private String mechanic;
private boolean finish;

public Bookings() {
}

public Bookings(String vehicle, String clerk, String service, String mechanic, boolean finish) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
    this.clerk = clerk;
    this.service = service;
    this.mechanic = mechanic;
    this.finish = finish;
}

public String getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}

public void setVehicle(String vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}

public String getClerk() {
    return clerk;
}

public void setClerk(String clerk) {
    this.clerk = clerk;
}

public String getService() {
    return service;
}

public void setService(String service) {
    this.service = service;
}

public String getMechanic() {
    return mechanic;
}

public void setMechanic(String mechanic) {
    this.mechanic = mechanic;
}

public boolean getFinish() {
    return finish;
}

public void setFinish(boolean finish) {
    this.finish = finish;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Bookings{" + "vehicle=" + vehicle + ", clerk=" + clerk + ", service=" + service + ", mechanic=" + mechanic + ", finish=" + finish + '}';
}
```

}

Comment: Are you asking about bookingListJCB.addItem(tempBooking)?  If you are, you are giving it a Bookings object (tempBooking).  Does your Bookings class have a @override toString() method that returns a String of all the fields you want to display?

Comment: Yes it does never thought of using it how do i make it populate the jcombobox ? And thank you for replying this is all pretty new to me

Comment: Can you post your Bookings class in your question? If you have an @override toString() in that class it should have been automatically called.

Comment: So what is bookingListJCBActionPerformed() doing wrong, and what do you want it to do? Also, isn't bookingListJCBActionPerformed() fired anytime you select an  item from the comboBox?

Comment: Well it isn't displaying any of the items from the array list, basically i want it to go through the array list using the for loop and every time it finds an array with 'boolean finish =  true' to add that array to the jcombobox